# eclipse: build path with other projects, how to prevent test src from being included?

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, path, project

in eclipse, I have project A, which depends on another project B.

now I add B to the build path of A. but since separately I need to run junit tests on B, I have the src/test/java and src/test/resources of B in the build path for B too. so when B is included in A's path, these src/test code is also included into A's path. this causes a lot of conflicts: for example, I declare the beans with same names in both projects, they have conflicts.

I know I can use m2eclipse plugin, but in many cases, my pom has special pre-compile plugins, so m2eclipse does not recognize these, and fails. so I have to do mvn eclipse:eclipse and generate a "regular" eclipse project , and work from there.

thanks!
Yang

Answer (score 1):

Source folders are automatically exported to dependent projects, so I think you're going to have to factor the B project test packages to another test project that depends on the original project B.

Ugly, but I can't think of another way to do it.